# using autosub on windows with python 39

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to use autosub as following

```
open CMD as Administrator
cd to scripts folder (cd <path>\Python\Python39\Scripts")
run command autosub -S fr -D fr "<path>\file.wav"
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ffmpeg: Executable not found on machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\Python\Python39\Scripts\autosub-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('autosub==0.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'autosub')())
  File "<path>\python\python39\lib\site-packages\autosub\__init__.py", line 397, in main
    subtitle_file_path = generate_subtitles(
  File "<path>\python\python39\lib\site-packages\autosub\__init__.py", line 245, in generate_subtitles
    audio_filename, audio_rate = extract_audio(source_path)
  File "<path>\python\python39\lib\site-packages\autosub\__init__.py", line 185, in extract_audio
    raise Exception("Dependency not found: ffmpeg")
  Exception: Dependency not found: ffmpeg
```

I have the ffmpeg exe file under \Python\Python39 folder

I also tried to run it as following

```
open CMD as Administrator
run command "<path>\Python\Python39\python.exe" "<path>\Python\Python39\Scripts\autosub.exe" -S fr -D fr "<path>\file.wav"
```

and got this error

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file <path>\Python\Python39\Scripts\autosub.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

What I'm doing wrong? what is the right way for using autosub?

- I have installed autosub using pip install git+https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub.git

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was

- remove those lines from \Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\autosub_*init*_.py

> ```
> if not which("ffmpeg")
> print("ffmpeg: Executable not found on machine.")
> ```

- Add path to ffmpeg.exe location under Environment Variables under System Varialbes -> Path (in my case path was C:\ffmpeg)
- Open CMD as Administrator
- cd to scripts folder (cd \Python\Python39\Scripts")
- run command autosub -S fr -D fr "\file.wav"

and it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

## Just one line change:

In `__init__.py`, line 183 (*line maybe change, but you can Ctrl+f this lines*):

```
# if not which("ffmpeg"):   # change from this
if not which("ffmpeg.exe"): # to this
```